# How to re-select radio button from post error?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form created in HTML but when I submit my form post and there is a error in the form validation, returning back is not remembering my initial radio selection.

```
var radio_options = $('form#contact input[type="radio"]');

for (var i=0; i< radio_options.length; i++) {
    var option =  radio_options[i];
    if (option.checked == true) {
      console.log(option.id); // how to I check this option to the appropriate radio?
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<form action="check.php" id="contact" method="post">

<div class="radioboxes"><strong id="top-more">Options</strong><br>
  <span class="othertopic" id="wwus"> <font>Please select one option</font></span>
  <div id="top-wwus"><input id="topic_252" name="form_tools_form_id" type="radio" value="252"> <label for="topic_252">Recruitment</label><br>
  <input id="topic_259" name="form_tools_form_id" type="radio" value="259"> <label for="topic_259">Requests</label><br>
  <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button> </div> </div> 
</form>
```

[image: console output]

I can access the values but I can't make them checked on the radio returning back to the original form after a error on validation. Can you see the problem in the js?

Comment: Your code is looking for the `checked` property of the `id` rather than the radio itself. Also, your `if` has `=` instead of `==`. I'd be remiss if I didn't mention that you're mixing jQuery and javascript here. If you're going to include jQuery, then you should use it for all your DOM manipulation rather than going back and forth.

Comment: @TylerRoper, you seem to know what you are saying, can you post a answer? I will be happy to accept you solution :)

Comment: How are you validating the form? In JavaScript or PHP? If the page is reloading when you submit the form, you can't retrieve the checked radios using your methodology. Their state will not be preserved across a page refresh.

Comment: PHP, but I don't have access to that file, as it uses formtools.

Comment: There is a huge javascript file with lots of code, and if I return it on top, it would remember the selection, so I am trying to add this to the end of the file.

Comment: I'm not clear on the methodology here. The code you've shared is just looking at the radio buttons on the screen and deciding if they're *currently* checked or not. It doesn't seem to relate to *previous* selections at all.

Comment: The use case is select a radio, submit. If error, returning back should remember the original choice. It works for all fields except the radio.

Comment: I understand that. Re-populating the selections with the original choices would require a back-end (PHP) effort to access the `$_POST` contents.

Comment: What’s to stop you from repopulating the form with php even if it failed validation?

Comment: @James, I was able to fix my issue with my own javascript code. Can only accept it tomorrow though. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    var radioValue = $("input[name='form_tools_form_id']:checked").attr('id');
    if(radioValue){
      localStorage.setItem('radioValue', radioValue);
    }
  });
  var givenRadioValue = localStorage.getItem('radioValue');
  $("#"+givenRadioValue).attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to 'remember' the selected value/radio.

If this is an AJAX request then store the selected radio in JavaScript prior to sending and then if there is an issue (e.g. error) then you can reset the appropriate form value(s) from the stored value(s).

If this a form submit where the page refreshes, then you are going to either pre-populate portions of the view (i.e. form) before returning the response or some other method such as hidden fields or setting a JavaScript variable in a script tag then accessing that on load.

Another option could be to use localStorage or cookies to set the form as you intend.

This is a generalized answer as there are many ways to accomplish this.